# Android App not working on API level >17

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-broadcastreceiver

I am developing an Android application that takes in a message and changes the profile. The app has one `Activity` and one `Broadcast Receiver`. The problem is that the app works perfectly fine for `API` level up till 17 but after that the `Broadcast Receiver` does not 
seem to work. I have mentioned the code of my `MainActivity` and `BroadCast Receiver` and also the `gradle` file.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText setPass;
    public Button submit;
    public static String password;
    //Context context;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    boolean b=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //context=getApplicationContext();
        setPass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.setPassEditId);
        submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButtonId);
        sharedPreferences= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Pritom",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    password = setPass.getText().toString();

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("password", password);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password saved successfully" + password, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //b=sharedPreferences.contains("password")?true:false;
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"b:"+b,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                sharedPreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Pritom",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Map<String,?> keys=sharedPreferences.getAll();
                for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry:keys.entrySet()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),entry.getKey()+":"+entry.getValue().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**MyReceiver.java**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public AudioManager audioManager;
    public String me = "";
    public String last = "";
    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
    public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    boolean b = false;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {

            sharedPreferences = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Pritom", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            b = sharedPreferences.contains("password") ? true : false;
            if (b) {
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Not present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String str = "";
            if (bundle != null) {
                String pass3 = sharedPreferences.getString("password", null);
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    //str += "n";

                    String smsBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    Log.d("Message",smsBody+pass3);
                    Toast.makeText(context,"pass:"+pass3,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (smsBody.equals("@general" + pass3)) {
                        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                            audioManager.setRingerMode(audioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

                    }
                }

                Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem in the `receiver` class is that none of the `Toast` messages are getting displayed in `API level>17(Jelly Bean)` but works perfectly fine in `API level<=17`

**build:gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shaloin.profile2"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

`

Comment: is it API 17+ for sure? or 23+? because in 23+ there is runtime permission.

Comment: how are you sending the broadcast? can you post the code?

Comment: I am using the default `messaging` app for sending message. I have already posted the code for `broadcast receiver` class.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine for `API up till 17` but after that it does not work.

Comment: Hmmm. what about your Manifest?

Comment: Where is your intent filter defined for the receiver?  The manifest?

Comment: @ViperAlpha , @DanielNugent I have updated my question and included the `manifest` file.

Comment: Check this link, does it help? https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: @ViperAlpha, I have gone through the link and made changes such as `intent-filters` and many more but it still didn't work :(

Comment: What does the logcat says

Comment: @PrakhaRaM, logcat shows the message that it receives for `API level<=17` but it does not show any message even if it receives for `API level>17`

Comment: can you paste it as it is, as I am executing well for below code.

Comment: Do you want the whole `logcat` or just the message being shown?

Comment: Try this 
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage smsMessage;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){//KITKAT
        SmsMessage[] msgs = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
        smsMessage = msgs[0];
        } else {
        Object pdus[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
        }
        Log.d("msf",smsMessage.getMessageBody());
    }

Comment: @PrakhaRaM, I did this : `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {


                    msgs = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
                    smsMessage = msgs[0];


                    if (smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString().equals("@general" + pass3)) {
                        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                        audioManager.setRingerMode(audioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    }
                }
`

Comment: But still didn't work

Comment: @PrakhaRaM, the `else` part works perfectly fine.

Comment: whats the error now, same?

Comment: Yes  same , the `if` part does not work , `else` part works fine

Comment: it works for me.

Comment: Can you please paste the whole `receiver` class code and can you please check if there are any more edits to be made in my code in the question. Thank you

Comment: what do you want exactly to do in receiver?

Comment: I want to receive the message along with the password I had saved in `shared preference` in the `Main Activity` and if the password matches the profile of the mobile changes. For example if the `password ` is `abcde` , I need to send a message `@generalabcde` because I want the profile to change from `silent` to `general` .